# how to create Map in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, dictionary

I want to use map in my JSF 2.0 website showing directions how to reach there (like [this](http://smart-kw.com/testingSite/index.php/miscellaneous/reach-us)).

Any idea/ suggestion how to make map in jsf 2.0 would be greatful.

Comment: There is [gmaps4jsf](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/) ortherwise why not simply output normal HTML/CSS/JavaScript?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie : I don't get what you meant by "why not simply output normal HTML/CSS/JavaScript"

Comment: You don't absolutely need JSF component to render HTML pages...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie : Ohh... I will do that... but for gmaps4jsf, I am not finding how to use them...

Comment: You only have to install the JAR and there is some examples [here](http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples2-3.0.0/pages/welcome.xhtml)

Comment: I have jar inside my lib folder, but I don't find example with full code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the gmaps4jsf library [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/), it has a component for directions [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps4jsf/wiki/directionComponent), but it is also noted that this component doesn't exists since version 3.0.0 so you will have to use older version.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by studying the API documentation and its examples here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Note that the Google maps API is not dependent on your server technologies. So (as Alexandre already pointed out) it does not matter what technology is on your server, as long as you are able to generate HTML/JS/CSS.